# Code pipeline to deploy multiple wars with single zip file

Tags: deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I am new to codepipeline and couldn't find how to configure Codedeploy to deploy multiple wars in single zip file in Elastic beanstalk. I can able to deploy single war successfully into Elastic beanstalk using codepipeline through AWS Mangement console. But my requirement is to have two war files in a single zip file which needs to be deployed in Elastic beanstalk.

Created Two Sources : Src1 and Src2

Created buildspec.yml for primary source Src1 and can able to create two artifacts with multiple input artifact [Using this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-multi-in-out.html).

My builspect.yml has these below lines.

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  secondary-artifacts:
    artifact1:
      base-directory: $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_source1
      files:
        - ROOT.war
    artifact2:
      base-directory: $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_source2
      files:
        - Support.war
```

Question 1) Now in Codedeploy, the input artifacts shows option to select either one of these two (ROOT.war or Support.war). I couldn't see an option to multiselect both wars together. How can i deploy two wars at the same time to elastic beanstalk in codepipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I did it by moving support.war to primary source location. The CodeBuild builds all the files from primary source location as output artifacts. So i updated the buildspec.file as follows

```
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo pre_build      
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto8
  post_build:
    commands:
      - mvn clean install
      - mv target/ROOT.war ROOT.war    
      - cd $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_support
      - mvn clean install
      - mv target/support.war $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/support.war
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```